# Best way to rig a cartoon mouth

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging, bones, shape-keys

so i have been experimenting A LOT with blender but this has got me stumped. I'm trying to make this character open his mouth very far (to his legs) and im wondering what the best way to go about this while also keeping the Lips and the body separate from each other. Any help i would very much appreciate.[image]

Comment: Suggestion.  Try using a armature.  Is there a hole for the mouth cavity?  You can search here at BSE for Armatures or Bones.  There are also tutorials on the famous video website.  Although the reader can guess ... the question is not providing much information.  Is the mouth floating on the body?  Does the head mesh move with the mouth.

Comment: There is a hole in the body mesh and the lips are parented to the body. Okay so my goal is to make it so when i distort the lips with shape keys  the mesh around the mouth follows the lips. so imagine the lips are stretching the skin of the body apart.

Comment: Armature Bones can move limbs as well as areas of soft flesh such as the mouth.  BSE awaits your display of the Armature Modifier.  Consider searching .. Bones Armature to move the mouth.